# UIImpactFeedbackGenerator impactOccurred Slight Delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, haptic-feedback

I'm using UIImpactFeedbackGenerator as described [in Apple's developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimpactfeedbackgenerator), but there seems to be a slight delay -- maybe a tenth of a second or similar -- between when I invoke impactOccurred and when you feel the haptic.  This is especially evident when I am playing a sound at the same time - the sound clearly precedes the haptic.

Someone else wrote about the same thing in [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/185026#185026), but no resolution.

I initialize the UIImpactFeedbackGenerator with:

```
// Set up impact
UIImpactFeedbackStyle sty = UIImpactFeedbackStyleMedium;
impactFeedbackGen = [[UIImpactFeedbackGenerator alloc] initWithStyle:sty];
```

Immediately call prepare, and call repeatedly during the few seconds that pass before the impact occurs:

```
[impactFeedbackGen prepare];
```

Then finally play the haptic, with:

```
[impactFeedbackGen impactOccurred];
```

Not sure if it's related, but I *am* using UISelectionFeedbackGenerator in the same app, but not at the same time.

Thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the trick with avoiding delay with UIImpactFeedbackGenerator is when to call `prepare`.

Obviously you can't simply call `prepare` and then immediate trigger the impact, since the engine needs time to actually prepare.

On the other hand, once `prepare` is called, the taptic engine will only stay in a prepared state for a short duration (a matter of seconds), in order to conserve power.

It is possible to extend the prepared state by calling `prepare` multiple times, however you have to be careful here as well, since after a certain threshold, the system will put the engine back to an idle state, and ignore further calls to `prepare` until after an impact is triggered.

Comment: Right, I read the documentation also -- I'm going it in advance by about 2 seconds or so typically.. have also tried shorter and longer timeframes, but there is always a delay.